# Android set divider for list item

Tags: android, android-listview

This is my **listview**:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:dividerHeight="1px"
        android:divider="@drawable/list_item_divider" >
```

and this is my divider `list_item_divider`

```
<shape
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shape="line">
 <stroke
   android:width="10dp"
   android:color="#8F8F8F"
   android:dashWidth="10dp"
   android:dashGap="10dp" />
</shape>
```

I can't see any divider in **listview**.
Help please.

Comment: give devider heigh a little more and try once..

Comment: @mvnpavan I did and the same result

Comment: give divider height in dp.

Comment: what if you remove this line? **android:dividerHeight="1px"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your drawable look this now

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <size android:height="3dip" />
    <solid android:color="#8F8F8F" />
</shape>
```

change it and try